# Interjection for agreement

Tags: word-usage, interjections

Edited:

Just as Hmm is a sound made when

> you pause while talking or when you are uncertain

Is there any interjection used in agreement?

Many a times during formal chat it so happens that I don't have much to say but I'm nodding in agreement. I wonder if there's any word that means agreement but isn't a texting term like 'mhm' .

Comment: Good question. "Hmm" does not signal agreement. It may signal that you are thinking about something. It may signal your disagreement even, I believe. Are you looking for a neutral interjection that signals agreement?

Comment: Thank you. I've edited my question.`Are you looking for a neutral interjection that signals agreement?` Yes I'm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Darwin is to believe, interjections are emission of  sounds efficient in highest degree as means of expression, rather, vocal expression. Interjections show rather than say. So gestures and postures enjoy all the more important roles in them. Contexts and  overlapping are thus an intrinsic part of it. What you are looking for is cultural, standardized vocalisations. On this score, we have to rely on the native speaker's judgement or intuitions. Culture, speech, modulation and sense of propriety and intonation differ from language to language. However, here is an indicative though not exhaustive list of condescending interjections, but guaranteeing no exclusive right to agreement alone.

- Ah!
- Aye!
- Eh?
- Mm-hmm!
- Olè! (from Spanish)
- Ooh!
- Uh-huh.
- Yay!
- Zowie!

Answer (score 0):

> "mhm"

is not just a texting term. It is perfectly appropriate to use in agreement in conversation.

Consider also "yea", "yeah", or "ok". Nodding does also work.

Comment: Can you cite a reference that says it is a standard English word? It is not to be found in dictionaries.

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh It is not a standard word, but neither is "hmm" in most dictionaries. It can still be used to express how you feel and people will understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Standard words used to agree while someone continues to talk about their points are

> yes
>   true
>   I agree
>   correct
>   right *(more so BrE)*
>   absolutely

nodding affirmatively while saying any of these also helps.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking for something that is a sound and can be used in written conversation after one has posted his/her opinion on something.